# login as400 from python automatically

Tags: python, ibm-midrange

I am trying to login to the IBM (AS/400) Python. Can I know how to connect?
I tried some code using telnet but it doesn't worked out.
Here is my code:

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "pub400.com"
user = "USER0123"
password = "user0123"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until(b"login: ")
```

Comment: I am unsure of what you are trying to do? If you are trying to access the console or "Green Screen" you will need to use IBM i Access. If you are trying to access the data your best bet from python is over ODBC.

Comment: @GenericDisplayName IBM i Access isn't necessary. An ordinary tn5250-Client will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The AS/400 platform uses extensions to the telnet protocol to define 1. the data format for cursor positioning and color/screen attributes as well as 2. a block oriented approach, 5250 and 3270 protocols are known for. It's like you fill out a web form (in a character based window): Editing is entirely done at client side. After filling out, you submit the whole form to the host for processing. It might be possible that the python telnetlib simply cannot cope with these special behavior.

Last, did you actually understand what your code snippet is supposed to do? I ask because your example code references the ordinary unix "login: " string but the AS/400's username field is called "User", and there is no colon afterwards. Did you try to use an ordinary vt100/telnet protocol client for testing purposes to connect and see what happens?

The AS/400's actually *can* talk vt100 but it's really clumsy, some kind of makeshift. No color support, F-Key handling is rarely working as expected. AS/400 Green Screens use F-Keys extensively. No UTF8, you need to set your console window to Latin 1 or whatever your country code on the AS/400 translates to. Special function keys like SysReq and Attn need multiple keystrokes to access these functions.

So, without a bit more input what you want to achieve, it's impossible to give advice. Additionally, "didn't work out" is not a helpful error description. Please always report actual error message texts. You can still update your initial question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. moreover , I am new to stack-overflow and so am not clear in question framing. but thanks for your piece of advice.  I

Comment: @kee_kee: Being precise in questioning isn't a Stackoverflow-only thing. Most often, if you can put your ideas into words, and describing what you tried, the answer is right in front of you. Nevertheless, if you feel that your question has been answered, please tag this entry as solved.